# Error running a test with selenium python on the console

Tags: python, selenium, console

It might seem like a silly question, but I'm really stuck and any help would be appreciated.

I exported a Selenim test case as I ran it using PyCharm Community, it runs correctly
and performs all appropriate tasks to do so. But if I try to run it using the console,
throws many errors. It happens with any test I try to run

Something like:

```
ERROR collecting tst_001.py _____________________________________________
C:\Python3.8\lib\site-packages\_pytest\python.py:513: in _importtestmodule
    mod = self.fspath.pyimport(ensuresyspath=importmode)
C:\Python3.8\lib\site-packages\py\_path\local.py:701: in pyimport
    __import__(modname)
<frozen importlib._bootstrap>:991: in _find_and_load
    ???
<frozen importlib._bootstrap>:975: in _find_and_load_unlocked
    ???
<frozen importlib._bootstrap>:671: in _load_unlocked
    ???
C:\Python3.8\lib\site-packages\_pytest\assertion\rewrite.py:152: in exec_module
    exec(co, module.__dict__)
tst_002.py:1: in <module>
    from src.functions.Functions import Functions as Selenium
..\functions\Functions.py:5: in <module>
    from functions.Inicializar import Inicializar
E     File "C:\Python3.8\lib\site-packages\functions.py", line 68
E      enter code here nodes = t`enter code here`uple(map(lambda (k, v): process_node(inner, k, v),
E                                ^
E   SyntaxError: invalid syntax
================================================== warnings summary ===================================================
C:\Python3.8\lib\site-packages\_pytest\junitxml.py:417
  C:\Python3.8\lib\site-packages\_pytest\junitxml.py:417: PytestDeprecationWarning: The 'junit_family' default value will change to 'xunit2' in pytest 6.0.
  Add 'junit_family=xunit1' to your pytest.ini file to keep the current format in future versions of pytest and silence this warning.
    _issue_warning_captured(deprecated.JUNIT_XML_DEFAULT_FAMILY, config.hook, 2)

-- Docs: https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/warnings.html
------------------- generated xml file: C:\Udemy.python-Selenium.Framework\src\results\results.xml --------------------
=============================================== short test summary info ===============================================
ERROR tst_002.py
!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! Interrupted: 1 error during collection !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
============================================= 1 warning, 1 error in 0.76s =============================================
```

Comment: Could you share your command in which you invoke the test from command line? Looks a copy/paste error to me.

Comment: python -m pytest tst_001.py --junit-xml = .. / results / results.xml